# D3 axis overlap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

https://jsfiddle.net/q5vwgxgz/3/

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(15)
  .tickSizeInner(25)
```

So the issue is that labels of the X axis overlap, Mon 31 and Novemeber.
From what I can see the space between axes for those two dates is smaller and in result the labels overlap.
Can I solve this somehow or it's a library issue?

[image]

The project where that chart is used in has dateselectors for start and end date and also a dropdown for date granularity(daily, monthly, yearly) which means that I can't use a fixed number of ticks and specific format.

```
.ticks(15)
```

is used here just for the demo, in the project it's like this

```
Math.min(data.length, Math.floor(width / 100)) // 100 being the 'min' tick width
```

---

Answer (score 6):

One solution (out of many) is specifically setting the tick format...

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%b %d")(d)
})
```

And spreading the ticks, for instance using `timeDay`:

```
.ticks(d3.timeDay.every(4))
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "2016-09-30",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-01",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-02",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-03",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-04",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-05",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-06",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-07",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-08",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-09",
  "Jobs": 4,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-10",
  "Jobs": 6,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-11",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-12",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-13",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-14",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-15",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-16",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-17",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-18",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-19",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-20",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-21",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-22",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-23",
  "Jobs": 4,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-24",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-25",
  "Jobs": 6,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-26",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-27",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-28",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-29",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-30",
  "Jobs": 5,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-10-31",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-01",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-02",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-03",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-04",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-05",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-06",
  "Jobs": 4,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-07",
  "Jobs": 5,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-08",
  "Jobs": 6,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-09",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-10",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-11",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-12",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-13",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-14",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-15",
  "Jobs": 3,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-16",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-17",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-18",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-19",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-20",
  "Jobs": 1,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-21",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-22",
  "Jobs": 2,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-23",
  "Jobs": 4,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-24",
  "Jobs": 0,
}, {
  "Date": "2016-11-25",
  "Jobs": 0,
}]
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Date = parseTime(d.Date);
});

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.Date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.Jobs);
  });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Date;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Jobs;
}));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(4))
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%b %d")(d)
  })
  .tickSizeInner(25)
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .select(".domain")
  .remove();

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .append("text")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "0.71em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Jobs");

g.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<svg width="1200" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, have in mind that in D3 time scales were not created having customizations in mind. Their behaviour is dynamic. Therefore, You'll have to fix each specific problem using ad hoc solutions.

Comment: Can work but the chart from the project has datepickers for Start and End date and also a date granularity dropdown which means I can't restrict it to a certain number of ticks or label format.

Answer (score 2):

Or you may rotate the label for ticks by 90 degrees:

```
d3.selectAll(".x-axis .tick text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-30, 50)rotate(-90)")
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/38ds4nkc/)

Comment: Unfortunately design requires them to be in a line :) thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Ok np can be helpful to someone looking for something similar.